# swift 3 date picker to display day month year only

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I use the following code in swift 3 to bring up date picker.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var eventStartText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    eventStartText.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: TextField Delegate
func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    //formatter.dateStyle = .full
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    eventStartText.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

    print("Try this at home")
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    print("This Worked")
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    eventStartText.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

// MARK: Helper Methods
func closekeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// MARK: Touch Events
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    closekeyboard()
}

/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */
```

}

How would i go about to only having day month and year.
and since i am asked to supply more details then to make things clear, what i need is for swift 3 date picker to display day month year only
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to show only day, month and year with picker then simply set `datePickerMode` property of `UIDatePicker` to `.date`

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
//set datePickerMode to date
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

textField.inputView = datePicker
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: but how to get date picker with only month and year ? Like in credit card expiry